# How to disambiguate between FieldAccess and QualifiedName?

Tags: code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm generating Java code as string, and I have expressions like

```
parameter.field.method();
```

Then I parse the generated code to AST with Eclipse JDT's `ASTParser`, and the subexpression

```
parameter.field
```

becomes a `QualifiedName`, not a `FieldAccess`. This causes problems because later I clean up the qualified names (using code from the [Clean Qualified Types Plugin](http://blog.mi-ernst.de/projekte)).

As the [JavaDoc of `FieldAccess`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.jdt/core/3.6.1/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/FieldAccess.java) states:

> An expression like "foo.bar" can be represented either as a qualified
>   name (`QualifiedName`) or as a field access expression (`FieldAccess`)
>   containing simple names. Either is acceptable, and there is no way to
>   choose between them without information about what the names resolve
>   to (`ASTParser` may return either).

What should I generate so that the parser can know unambiguously that this is a `FieldAccess`?

(An interesting side-question: how does the Java compiler disambiguate between the possibilities? Whenever it encounters a `QualifiedName`, it also tries to interpret it as a `FieldAccess` by resolving the names?)

Answer (score 1):

The minimal solution I found is to generate parentheses around the parameter:

```
(parameter).field.method();
```